# Methods to create a function that represent directly definite integral?

Tags: calculus

Exist some method to create directly from integral some function $g$ that

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)=g(b-a)$$

Maybe that only some kind of $f(x)$ can be transformed in this way and many other no.

Sorry if the question is so wide but, in any case, can you enlighten me on this question in any way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general integrand $f$, such a function cannot exist.

To see this, let $c>0$ and compare

$$I_1=\int_{a}^{a+c}f(x)dx$$

and

$$I_2=\int_{b}^{b+c}f(x)dx$$

for $a \ne b$. In general, $I_1 \ne I_2$, but the hypothetical function $g$ would receive the same argument $c$ for both integrals.

Comment: YES, thank you very much... it was obvious after all, I dont though too much the question by myself, lol.

Comment: I will wait some time if someone want answer the question.

Comment: Sure. Note that this argument also shows that such a function $g$ can be found if and only if $f$ is constant, as otherwise $a,b,c$ can always be chosen in such a way that $I_1\ne I_2$.

Comment: (Note that in the above comment I have assumed Riemann integration, as with Lebesgue integration there are non-constant functions like $\mathbb I_{\mathbb Q}$ whose integral depends only on the length of the integration interval.)